# JDOM HTML to XML Conversion - parent node selfend tag generating eventhough it having a child node

Tags: xml, jdom, tag-soup, xmlconvert

JDOM parser used for parsing and conversion of html file to XML file. After parsing the html file self end tag generating even though it has a child node.
Input Html

```
<li id="fieldId1" fieldtype="dropdownFromList">
    <span>
    <sflabel path="polProdCode">
    <fmtmessage key="mpolicy.policy.polProdCode.lable" />
    </sflabel>
    </span>
</li>
```

OutputXML

```
         <span>
         <sflabel path="polProdCode" />  ---sflabel tag selfclosing after the conversion
         <fmtmessage key="mpolicy.policy.polProdCode.lable" />
         </span>
```

Expected XML

```
          <span>
          <sflabel path="polProdCode" >
          <fmtmessage key="mpolicy.policy.polProdCode.lable" />
          </sflabel>      ----need endtag
          </span>
```

Java Code

```
    SAXBuilder saxBuilder = new SAXBuilder("org.ccil.cowan.tagsoup.Parser", false);
File log = new File("log.html");
        org.jdom.Document jdomDocument = saxBuilder.build(log);
        XMLOutputter outputter = new XMLOutputter(Format.getPrettyFormat());

            fwOutXml = new FileWriter("output.xml");
            bwOutXml = new BufferedWriter(fwOutXml);
            outputter.output(jdomDocument, bwOutXml);
```

Comment: This is almost certainly an issue in the tagsoup library.... JDOM is not actually the parser, it's just an in-memory model. The tagsoup library is the parser and it must be giving the wrong events on the SAX stream.

Comment: Is there any alternate saxDriverClass to overcome this issue?

Answer (score 0):

I've fixed the conversion by removing the saxdriverclass and left empty

```
     SAXBuilder saxBuilder = new SAXBuilder();
```